# C# deserialize json with array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, data-conversion

I want to deserialize a json that contains an array into a class and i dont know how it works. I am using C# WPF. What i got to work so far:

Class:

```
class Truppe
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int nr { get; set; }
    public int tribe { get; set; }
}
```

Json Deserialize:

```
Troop = "{\"id\":1,\"nr\":1,\"tribe\":1}";
Truppe JSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truppe>(Troop);
```

so far it works totally fine. But now i want an array in the class containing the costs as an array. So it shall look something like that (not working)

Class:

```
class Truppe
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int nr { get; set; }
    public int tribe { get; set; }
    public int[,] costs { get; set; }
}
```

Json Deserialize:

```
Troop = "{\"id\":1,\"nr\":1,\"tribe\":1,\"costs\":{\"1\":75,\"2\":50,\"3\":100,\"4\":0}}";
Truppe JSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Truppe>(Troop);
```

can someone help me get the correct form?

Comment: It should look like a jagged 2d JSON array.  Try serializing an example of your class with `costs = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };` and you should see the correct format.

Comment: it should be something like this `"costs":[[1,2],[3,4]]`. Currently your json doesn't contain any arrays

Comment: Do you have full control over the class structure and/or the JSON format? As @dbc mentioned if you have control over the json, just deserialize an instance of your class and see what it looks like. If you working to a fixed JSON structure then go with what Pavel said which is essential the json doesn't contain an array, so update your class or you will need custom logic

Comment: I could modify the Json. The best case would be if its possible with that syntax of Json. I could turn the array into a List if that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out how it works with that Syntax of Json. Instead of

```
public int[,] costs { get; set; }
```

i had to use

```
public Dictionary<string, int> costs { get; set; }
```